# How to preserve escaped string in shell pipe?

Tags: bash, sh

I have a log file with json entries. To tail it I do the following:

```
tail -f path/to/logfile | while read line; do echo $line | json ; done
```

`json` -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/json

The problem is that the json can contain escaped strings as values and echoing them eliminates the escaping.

```
{"a":"\"Hello\""} -> {"a":""Hello""}
```

Comment: Can you show us an actual content of logfile containing escaped strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does

```
tail -f path/to/logfile | while read -r; do echo "$REPLY" | json ; done
```

fix it?

I know `read` interprets `\` escapes by default, and it does weird things if you specify variables to read into.

I also know that using unquoted variables in shell scripts is a recipe for trouble.

Hence `read -r` to disable backslash processing, using `$REPLY` instead of `$line`, and quotes around `"$REPLY"`.

---

I've also had a look at the `json` documentation. It has a thing called "streaming". Would

```
tail -f path/to/logfile | json -ga
```

do what you want?

Comment: @cdarke It splits on any character listed in `IFS`, even if you specify just one variable (at least according to the documentation). This leads me to believe it will strip leading (and possibly trailing) spaces, when all we really want is to read a line verbatim. (And I can never remember the details, so I just don't specify variables with `read`.)

Comment: The last one did it (json with streaming option)! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding `echo` for strings that might contain backslashes (or start with "-" or ...), since some versions of `echo` will try to interpret escape sequences in the string. Sometimes. It's messy. Use `printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"` instead; it's much more predictable.